# Hadoop InvalidInput Exception

Tags: exception, hadoop, input, hdfs

```
root@priyal-Inspiron-N5030:/home/priyal# hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal in /in
root@priyal-Inspiron-N5030:/home/priyal# hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar wordcount in out

INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032

INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1424175893740_0008
```

**org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/in**

can someone plz suggest what exactly the problem is and how do i resolve ? I am a new user

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/in
```

says that the destination location `/user/root/in` is not prsrent in your **HDFS**. You can brows your file system using simple web UI.

http://localhost:50070/

then click on **Utilities** drop down -> **Brows the file System**. and check your foledr hirerchy i.e. **/user/root/in**

if it does not exist you can create folder using command

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/in
```

now try to execute your copy command

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /local/path/of/source/file hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/in
```

hope this will help you :)